# Changing listview dividers on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I`m learning JQM and have a lot of questions. Not asking if not trying to do many things.

I have a listview element. When page is loaded it sets listview with autodivider alphabetically by name. When you click on the "category" navigation button it sets elements according to its category, grouping. All is fine there.

My problem is when trying to go back clicking on the "names" navigation button nothing changes. Please help.

Here is simplified sample: http://jsfiddle.net/smatisen/v382r874/

```
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Test</h1>

    <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="setNamesOrder" class="ui-btn-active">Name</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="setTableOrder">Category</a></li>
       </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" class="todo-listview">
                <li data-category="cat 1"><a href="" data-view-id="1" class="view"><h2>Test Name 1</h2></a></li>
                <li data-category="cat 2"><a href="" data-view-id="2" class="view"><h2>Test Name 2</h2></a></li>
                <li data-category="cat 1"><a href="" data-view-id="3" class="view"><h2>Test Name 3</h2></a></li>

            </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by adding hide and show elements on button click events and clonin listview with different class name. Not sure if this is elegant, but it is working. http://jsfiddle.net/smatisen/v382r874/2/

```
$(document).on('click', '#setTableOrder', function(event) {
        console.log("DEBUG - SetTableOrder clicked");
        $('.byNamelistview').closest('.ui-listview').hide();
        $('.todo-listview').closest('.ui-listview').show();
        showRecordsByCat();
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your jsFiddle code, when you click on the "Name" navigator button, the function that you have written called "showRecordsByName" is called.  The code of that looks as follows:

```
function showRecordsByName()
{
    $('.todo-listview').listview({
        autodividers: true
    });
    $('.todo-listview').listview("refresh");
}
```

And ... that's all it does.  It refreshes the listview with class ".todo-listview" but since the content of the list has not changed in any way, it remains exactly as it was before this code was executed.

Thank you for using jsFiddle, it makes examination much easier.

Comment: Surprisingly your answer may of use. I should definitely change the page :-) Let me try

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is modify the autodividersSelector on the show records by name function to get the first letter of the text:

```
function showRecordsByName(){
    $('.todo-listview').listview({
        autodividers: true,
        autodividersSelector: function (li) {
            var out = li.text().charAt(0);
            return out;
        }
    });
    $('.todo-listview').listview("refresh");
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/v382r874/4/)**